# Execute binary file from volume inside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very new to Docker and containers. I want to run a game server inside a docker container.

When I add the binary file for starting the server in the `Dockerfile` with `COPY`, I can run the binary file inside the container and everything works fine.

But my goal is to create the docker image without the binary file. I want to add the binary file with a `volume` to `docker run` or `docker-compose`. When the `volume` is added to the container, I see all files inside the container and the permissions are also set correct. But when I want to execute the binary file e.g. `./binaryfile` I get this error inside the container: `Trace/breakpoint trap` and the game server does not start.

Host: `Ubuntu 20.04`

Container base image: `ubuntu:14.04`

Comment: That seems like an odd requirement.  How would the binary get into the volume?  Why not just build it into the image, and run the container normally?  Can you provide a [mcve]; is there a programming question involved, or are you just trying to run binaries in containers without using Docker's image system?

Comment: the binary gets created on another machine and transfered via nfs to the docker host

Comment: A more typical Docker workflow would `docker push` an image containing the binary to a registry, and then you can `docker run` that image without actually involving volumes or manually copying binaries around.

Comment: Yes, this should work without a problem. The volume is mounted before the command is run, so you can definitely run something mounted in a volume.

Dynamic linking might make this complicated though. Are you sure that the executable that you're copying into the container is a static executable, or that it has been built against a libc/shared-libraries location that is identical in your container?